# Использование ComboBox в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть простой `xaml`:

```
<ComboBox
    Height="23" Name="status"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source="?"}"
    Width="120">
</ComboBox>
```

Что нужно написать на `c#`, чтобы поместить элементы в выпадающий список, вот сюда:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source="?"}"
```

Именно не из базы, а вручную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу ошибаться, но по-моему, `ComboBox` поддерживает непосредственное содержимое. Т.е. можно задать элементы так:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBoxItem ...>some item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem ...>some item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem ...>some item 3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

На уровне выше (где лежит ваш `ComboBox`) или в нем самом нужно уточнить `DataContext`. Это может быть почти что угодно, но лично Я использую сам класс окна или `control-а`.

```
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Потом в привязке я просто указываю на `public property`. В Вашем случае - это `ComboBox`, поэтому свойство должно быть похоже на массив. Привязка такая:

```
   ItemsSource="{Binding мое_свойство}"
```

А пример свойства просто:

```
   public ObservableCollection<string> мое_свойство { get; set; }
```

Потом в конструкторе или в любом другом месте вы просто заполняете или удаляете элементы в этом свойстве. В отличие от `List<string>     ObservableCollection` сам обновляет Ваш `ComboBox` автоматически.

Удачи!